# display a confirmation popup on button click based on condition

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:commandButton` on click of which I need to add a few values to a list. In my managed bean, I'm validating the value that has to be added, and if it validates to false, I have to display a confirmation popup. This is my code -

```
<p:commandButton id="add" value="Add" type="submit"                                      action="#{bean.doAdd}" ajax="false"
update=":List"/>
```

And in the bean, on click of the "Add" button,

```
public String doAdd() throws Exception {
        if(response != null) {
            if(keyList.contains(response))  {
                if(!responseList.contains(response)) {
                    responseList.add(response);
                } 
            } else {
               //Have to display confirmation popup.
            }
            response = "";
        }

        return response;
    }
```

I'm using jsf 2.0 and primefaces 3.0. Can someone please tell me how to display the popup from the bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RequestContext` to run js code inside your managed bean

Make sure its an ajax call  - got no `ajax="false"`

like this

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
context.execute("YourDialogwidgetVar.show()");
```

I assume you got some dialog defined...

```
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" message="Hello"  
                header="Header" widgetVar="YourDialogwidgetVar">  
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: do you have primefaces included in your project ? add `import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;` to your bean...

Comment: I do have primefaces included, had used a wrong import before. Corrected it and tried what you suggested, but it's throwing a null pointer exception.

Comment: is your bean a managed bean ? something like : `@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped`

Comment: try to return null in `response` cause otherwise your bean will be destroyed , try to see if it works with session scope too...

Comment: I was returning response as blank, and I tried returning it as null too, doesn't work. Session scope doesn't work either..

Comment: show the code of the commandButton , make sure its an ajax call (got no `ajax="false"`)

Answer (score 0):

This code may helpfull to you.

```
private boolean valid = true; 

public void doAdd() {
    valid = false;
}


<p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Basic Dialog" visible="#{!testBean.valid}">
    <h:outputText value="Message!" />
</p:dialog>

<h:commandButton id="modalDialogButton" value="Modal" action="#{testBean.doAdd}"/>
```