# Show Primefaces Dialog box after checking condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a text box which gets the Book ID and deletes the record at button click. If the text box is left empty, it deletes all the records in the database.

```
<h:inputText id="txtBookID" label="txtBookID" value="#{db_work_Bean.bookID}" />
<p:commandButton value="Delete Book"  update="table" 
       action="#{db_work_Bean.doDeleteBook}">                               
    <f:param name="bukID" value="#{db_work_Bean.bookID}"  style="width:120px;"/>                    
</p:commandButton>
```

What I want is to check if the text box is left empty, then it should first show p:confirmDialog to confirm whether to delete all the records or not. I know I'll have to check the value of text box in JavaScript, but how can I,

1. Call the p:confirmDialog from JavaScript
2. Call the "action" method in the managed bean once it is confirmed?

Following is my p:confirmDialog code:

```
<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="warning" header="You are about to delete all the records!" 
    message="Do you wish to continue?">
  <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" onclick="warning.hide()" 
    actionListener="#{db_work_Bean.changeDeleteAllBooksCheck}" 
    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
  <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" onclick="warning.hide()" 
    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: I think you can show the dialog from the bean, and create your own buttons which calls an actionlistener by own choice. Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228351/display-a-confirmation-popup-on-button-click-based-on-condition. Oh, your yes-button already calls an actionlistener, why do you need to call an action too?

Comment: Does it have to be pure `javascript` or can that be validated from the bean? BTW, To call `p:confirmDialog` you can use `PF('warning').show();` where `warning` is the dialog's `widgetVar`.